# Disable loading spinner when listview content is loaded

Tags: android, facebook, listview

I have this code for the listview:

```
@Override
        public void onComplete(List<Profile> friends) {

            // populate list
            List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Profile profile : friends) {
                //profile.getInstalled();
                values.add(profile.getName());          
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> friendsListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_items2, values);
            friendsListAdapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
                    return lhs.compareTo(rhs);    
                }
            });
```

And this custom spinner with animation:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageSpinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/custom_spinner2" />
```

The listview loads content from facebook, and the when the content is done loading i want the spinner to disappear, but what i have now is that the spinner is there even when the content is loaded. This is what i have tried adding to the onComplete method:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                });
```

But with this code the spinner is still there when the content is loaded, any ideas what is wrong with the code?

I solved it by adding clearAnimation(); right after the setVisibility(View.GONE);, 
like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mSpinner.clearAnimation();
                }
                });
```

Now it works perfectly!

Comment: How's your mSpinner is initialized?

Comment: I can't try myself, because I don't have the animation code. Can you try not adding animation and trying to hide spinner? And are we sure runOnUiThread runs?

Comment: I tried setting clearAnimatin(); in runOnUiThread, and that worked, but somehow the (View.GONE); doesn't :/

Comment: @interlude i updated the question with the animation aswell if you want to test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this happens because your animation is running always. Just hide your animation on runOnUiThread. Or use default ProgressBar.

Comment: How can i hide the animation?

Comment: what it does now with clearAnimation(); is that the spinner is there,  it just "freezes" and the animation stops

Answer (score 0):

Maybe listening for events such as `onLayout` from an instance of [`ViewTreeObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html) which you can get for your `ListView` might work.

Try using something like this (adjust it to fit your composition).

```
yourListView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            yourListView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```